# How can i convert my google analytics web app into mobile app?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a mobile apps that i applied my google analytics track IDs but when i create the google analytics app profiles i initially choose web app instead of mobile app. while exploring around the settings, I could not find a switch to convert it into mobile app. I have more than 10 app with different google analytics track id, so i don't think creating new profile is great solution, there might be switch to change it to mobile app.

Someone out there might have encounter this situation. please help.

Solution:

What i did to solved this was create a new App, same name with the web one, then set it to mobile and then delete the web app.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is actually the incorrect.  Specially if you have a existing web profile which as lots of historical data.  Here is how to solve this by keeping your existing web property.

You add a profile view on your existing Web Property which can be a Mobile Ap Profile.  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009714?hl=en

The big clue came from this Upgrade to Universal Analytics post https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/mobile-sdk

"To get access to new app reports and features, you will need to upgrade to v2.x or higher of the SDK and create at least one app view (profile) in your reports to view the data. Any new data sent from your app will only be available in this new app view (profile), while your old data will continue to be available in the original web view (profile). Learn more about the latest version of the SDK for Android or iOS."

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to change the type of tracking after the profile is created. You will have to create new profile IDs and update the apps.