# Documentation re: Mixing Web and Mobile App Google Analytics IDs on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I've found a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593820/google-analytics-not-working-ios) of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849941/how-can-i-convert-my-google-analytics-web-app-into-mobile-app) indicating that a google analytics tracking id created for web cannot be used with the mobile SDK.  [One post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829584/google-analytics-in-ios-not-working#comment32426275_19052889) does link to supporting documentation, but google has since updated that page.

Can anyone point me to up to date documentation that clearly states that web ids cannot be used in a mobile app (specifically, iOS)?  My experience indicates that this is true, but I would like to show documentation directly from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That used to be the case, that you couldn't mix website and mobile apps within the same GA property (Google's term for the tracking ID).

However, it appears it changed earlier this year and Google removed all references to the restriction from their sites:

https://plus.google.com/+GoogleAnalytics/posts/LCLgkyCn4Zi

Google have done work to support this so the views make sense, for example visitors have become users and visits have become sessions. You can also add filters to views if you want to keep the data separate.